# Outlook 2013 32-bit crashes when syncing Gmail via IMAP

Tags: sync, crash, gmail, microsoft-outlook-2013

I setup **Outlook 2013 32-bit** to sync all mail from my **Gmail** account via IMAP.
Then I setup **gSyncit** add-on to sync calendar and contacts too.

The day I installed everything was working fine. Mail was being synced, calendar was synced, contacts were synced. Then next day I start my PC and launch **Outlook 2013 32-bit** - it started to crash.
After **Outlook 2013 32-bit** is launched, 5-8 seconds pass and it crashes everytime. Seems like it crashes because of mail syncing. I have a lot of emails(more than 10k). Googling didn't yield helpful information.

Why would it crash today when everything was working and syncing fine yesterday and how do i fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to launch Outlook in `Safe Mode`?

Comment: @Ramhound
No.I will try. If it works - will I need to launch it in `Safe Mode` always?

Comment: I just tried `Safe Mode`, but it still crashed.

Comment: If you don't have attempt to sync your mail does Outlook crash?  Did you install the 32-bit or 64-bit version of Outlook?  Update your question to reflect this new information.

Comment: Steve, does this happen when you close as many other apps as you can (including AV if safe to do so)